# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, newvar, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 139

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me why my function won't work? Everything works when it is not in a function. Please see below:

```
scale.it<-function(df,var,newvar){

  varn <- as.numeric(df$var)

  last <- max(varn)

  df$newvar <- (varn/last)

  return(df)
}

scale.it(go.cubs.go,PAge,IPAge)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, newvar, value = numeric(0)) : replacement 
has 0 rows, data has 139
```

Comment: Please use `code` tags or indent blocks of code by 4 spaces to make your code more readable.

Comment: What do you expect this function to do? What data are you running it on? Does the data have a column named `var` that you're referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
scale.it<-function(df,var,newvar){

  varn <- as.numeric(df[, var])

  last <- max(varn)
  print(last)
  df[, newvar] <- (varn/last)

  return(df)
}


myDf <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = 1:5)

scale.it(myDf,"x","xNew")
#   x y xNew
# 1 1 1  0.2
# 2 2 2  0.4
# 3 3 3  0.6
# 4 4 4  0.8
# 5 5 5  1.0
```

The `var` and `newvar` will be interpreted literally if you use `df$var` or `df$newvar`

That being said, there is a function in `r` called `scale` which does what you are trying to do here. For example you can do this:

```
myDf$xNewNew <- scale(myDf$x, center = F, scale = max(myDf$x))
#   x y xNewNew
# 1 1 1     0.2
# 2 2 2     0.4
# 3 3 3     0.6
# 4 4 4     0.8
# 5 5 5     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I needed.